# gridview: How to get a value from database cell of the current edited row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm using : 1.A Gridview 2.SqlDataSource to bind set the table data information to gridview.

I want to get from the edited row in gridview the value of a cell from database of the same row.

thanks

Comment: okay,look again at my question please

Comment: Looks like there is some trigger on ur table

Comment: but now?I just want to insert the value of the edited cell in the database in the same row , so if I edit from ROW no9. the value from a column called: age , the value will be updated in the database in the row no9. cell age

Comment: It sounds like you should read up more on GridView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

Comment: sorry , I'm tired look again at my question please , that's what I want

Answer (score 0):

In that case, simply on the edit click, grab the id field of that row (maybe it is hidden)
and bind another gridview by that same id.
I am assuming these tables join by id.

Comment: well , I don't want to bind it in other gridview I want to get from the edited row something like : Select * FRom tablename columnName where id=id , something like that ,

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can use is DataKeyNames Gridview property. Check [GridView.DataKeyNames Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)